# How folders DCIM Download WhatsApp media redirect link binded location changed to SD card?

Tags: downloading, mount, bind-mount, folder-organizer

As in  PC windows we can change default location of my documents by roaming profile or registry settings  is it possible to

Change default storage location   (link bind redirect automove) of DCIM Download WhatsApp media Facebook or any folders to externL memory card so thT whatever saved is automatically moved or downloaded or saved in external  card Automatically through and shell commands without or on  rooted mobile kindly share link or step by step commands ways to do the same with any folders in android

Is there any app which automove or is there any script which automoves without rooting. Eg:foldermount app (but works in rooted mobile)

Comment: you can use macrodroid to run scheduled script but i think the problem is with permissions

Comment: @alecx bro thanks for suggestion is there any app to upload or sync on cloud storage or sd memory external card every as you  suggested folder sync and deleted the comments will folder sync work for cloud or as card

Comment: I have same problem on huawei device with FBE (adoptable-storage not available) someone suggested folder sync, will try thx